# How can I make a line break in text of draftwatermark?

Tags: draftwatermark

I am trying to use a line break in the text of my watermark created with `draftwatermark`, however this does not seem to work.

Any idea, what I am doing wrong? According to the manual it should work:
Section 3.3 of the manual:
*As previously noticed, the watermark text can be specified with thetextoption. Thevalue passed to thetextoption does not need to be a plain string. Conversely, it mayinclude formatting marks, such as line break commands (e.g.,\) or commands to selectfont variants (e.g.,\bfseries).*

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[anchor=cb,vpos=220mm,color=black,angle=0]{draftwatermark}
\DraftwatermarkOptions{text={© by me\\ and someone else}}
\title{Test document}
\author{\textcopyright Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

As this seems to be a bug, I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/callegar/LaTeX-draftwatermark/issues/21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code says so, but the code doesn't confirm this. You can add e.g. a tabular. And you should set the fontsize, the default is very large (as you would see if you would use a scalable font)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[anchor=cb,vpos=220mm,color=black,angle=0,fontsize=20pt]{draftwatermark}
\makeatletter
\DraftwatermarkOptions{text={\begin{tabular}{l}© by me\\ and someone else\end{tabular}}}
\title{Test document}
\author{\textcopyright Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Once more a sleak way around a limitation that wasn't supposed to be a limitation.

Comment: I opened an issue report on GitHub: https://github.com/callegar/LaTeX-draftwatermark/issues/21